# How to customize Google Play service notifications

Tags: push-notification, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm using Google Play services to make a turn-based game. When a user invites friends or takes a turn while playing, Google will send a notification, but it can't directly open my game (instead, it will open the Google Play services app).

Can I modify that notification?

Can I use Parse to push my own notifications instead of using Google's default notification?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your notification has to be handle in app side.
In notification you are sending some data may be in form of json,you have to parse data and using NotificationManager you can customise your operation i.e. open the app or open google play service.

Comment: First thanks for your answer, but seem google not provide method to custom that notification, i can use my own push to do what you say above but at least i need disable default notification by google.

Comment: yes at a time single notification can be used.remove default google notification. You can use 3rd party such as pushwoosh...it might help you..https://github.com/mhartington/com.pushwoosh.plugins.pushwoosh/blob/master/src/android/src/com/arellomobile/android/push/PushGCMIntentService.java

Comment: so if i use push service from 3rd party like Parse, it will auto override default google notification or i have to do something?